# Redis EC2 Replica for Elasticache

Tags: amazon-ec2, redis, amazon-elasticache

Is it possible to create a Redis Replica for Elasticache on an EC2 instance?

The setup I want to do is to write to the master node, and replicate that information to multiple EC2 nodes in order to read this info directly from localhost with no network latency. I need to read large sets of data with fast performance.

Is this possible? If it is, is it a good approach?

Comment: AFAIK this isn't possible w/ EC, but you should contact their support for a definite answer and please share it here for future generations to come.

Answer (score 0):

Not only is it possible, this is a standard practice and is implemented for you automatically when you create a Redis setup. AWS allows you to configure extra nodes in the same or different regions and provides two DNS endpoints.

One is used to access the master node and is what receives all set/get traffic. The secondary node(s) are used to replicate the data in master with a small delay in consistency and can also function as a "read-only" node.

If your main node goes down Elasticache will handle elevating a secondary node to primary status.